# How to become a Sitecore MVP? webinar

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**September 29th 3pm UTC (8am Pacific/11am Eastern/4pm UK/5pm Central European)**

Please join us for a Masterclass on How to become a Sitecore MVP. We invited Pablo Peralta, 10-time Microsoft MVP and the author of the book "Becoming the Most Valuable Professional in Your Tech Community" (https://www.becomemvp.com/) to share his experience with you. Pablo will share the principles, strategies, most common mistakes to avoid, habits to develop, and secrets you need to know.

Registration: https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/6362697177815623435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recording of the How to become a #SitecoreMVP webinar is now available on the Master Sitecore YouTube channel. https://siteco.re/becomemvp